# How can i switch elements in tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

What would be the easiest (shortest) way to switch elements in tuple?

```
my_tuple= (a,b)
```

After switch:

```
new_tuple= (b,a)
```

Answer (score 0):

By reversing it:

```
>>> my_tuple = ('a', 'b')
>>> new_tuple = my_tuple[::-1]
>>> new_tuple
('b', 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [32]: my_tuple= ('a','b')

In [33]: tuple(reversed(my_tuple))
Out[33]: ('b', 'a')
```